# HttpClient java.net.UnknownHostException exception when the CURL command passes

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use httpclient to make make a call to Jenkins to get a list of jobs.

When I run my code, I get an `UnknownHostException`.

I tried to make the same request using `curl` and I was able to get the result. I am not sure how to interpret this.

```
void nwe() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("https://<JENKINS_URL>/api");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("/json");
    httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target, httpGet, localContext);
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());

}
```

The CURL command on the same URL gives me the expected output

Thanks,
Amar

Comment: Not much to go on, but use `curl -v` and check whether you are connecting via a proxy server.  Make sure you are using fully-qualified host names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [JavaDoc for `HttpHost`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpHost.html#HttpHost%28java.lang.String%29):

> **Parameters**: hostname - the hostname (IP or DNS name)

So you should use just (omit the protocol and context):

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost( "<JENKINS_URL>" );
```

and then `HttpGet` the `/api/json` part.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you SIr!!!! This led to a problem where the host name verification was failing. I took care of it and now it works...I have accepted this as an answer